# Large companies on Magento 2 CE

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade

I'd like to find out real world experience on Magento CE (version 2).

- Any large scale implementation on CE version?
- Implemented headless commerce with CE?
- Performance issues, bugs, feature limitations (if any)?
- How easy/difficult is to upgrade from CE to EE?

Reason for asking this is that my team is evaluating if we should go for Magento EE or CE from day one. Our business has a vision to grow the platform to cover multiple channels (omni-channel).

The license cost for EE is currently prohibitive.

We are considering to go with CE version first and explore upgrading later to EE version, assuming it is easy.